# Travel time alert a la Calendar

Tags: ios

[image: Calendar time to leave feature]

For the built in Calendar app on iOS, Apple provides a feature that will alert you of the travel time to your calendar event. I was wondering how Apple accomplishes this. It seems like calendar notifications would simply be local notifications, but does Apple use remote notifications in order to calculate travel time? To be more specific, I'm looking for how Apple actually implemented this using the UNNotifications framework in iOS. Is there some pre-display hook that local notifications have? Is Calendar tracking the user in the background in order to keep traffic times?

Comment: General note: Apple can do whatever they want. There always exists the very real possibility they use a feature that simply is not available to the normal developer. That being said: no idea about your specific situation, what happens in airplane mode? Does it factor in real-time data like traffic jams or train delays?

Comment: Good thinking! I have no idea what happens with travel time notifications if the user has airplane mode on. I'd assume it just wouldn't work as it couldn't communicate with the maps api